# Determining if friends of a user work in a similar field

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

The purpose of this function is to find friends of the active user who work in a certain field. I've run similar functions on current location, college and major but can't get to seem to get this one to work. So I'm looking for friends of the active user who work in real estate, finance, etc.

```
  function NewBuddies () {
       $config = array(
       'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
       'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
       );
       $facebook = new Facebook($config);
       $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
       try {
       $fql    =   "select uid,name,work from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
       $param  =   array(
       'method'    => 'fql.query',
       'query'     => $fql,
       'callback'  => ''
       );
       $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
       }
       catch(Exception $o){
       d($o);
       }

       $friends = $fqlResult;
       $friends_BA = array();
       foreach ($friends as $friend) {
       $isBA = false;
           if (is_array($friend['work'])) {
              foreach ($friend['work'] as $school) {
                 if (isset($school)) {
                    foreach ($school['employer'] as $name) {
                       $lowerName = strtolower($name);
                       if (strpos($lowerName, 'company') !== false || strpos($lowerName, 'corporation') !== false) {
                       $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                       continue 3; // skip to the next friend


                       }
                     }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($friends_BA);
             echo '</pre>';
      }
```

Here is an example of a similar function that does work. It retrieves a list of the Facebook users friends who live in the same city:

```
  function getLocalFriends () {
             $config = array(
             'appId' => 'XXXXXX',
             'secret' => 'XXXXX',
             );
             $facebook = new Facebook($config);
             $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
             try {
             $fql    =   "select name,current_location from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
             $param  =   array(
             'method'    => 'fql.query',
             'query'     => $fql,
             'callback'  => ''
             );
             $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
             }
                 catch(Exception $o){
             d($o);
             }

             $friends = $fqlResult;
             $friends_BA = array();
             foreach ($friends as $friend) {
               $isBA = false;
               if (is_array($friend['current_location'])) {
                  $lowerName = strtolower($friend['current_location']['city']);
                      if (strpos($lowerName, 'orlando') !== false || strpos($lowerName, 'altamonte springs') !== false) {
                      $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
            }
         }
       }
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($friends_BA);
             echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/ ...and...            http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ ...may help

Answer (score 0):

You might not be getting any results because you might not be requesting the correct permissions.  friend_work_history will be needed.

Comment: Those permissions are granted

Comment: My next suggestion is to step thru the code as it is running using a debugger tool and check to see what values you have at what point.

Comment: Why is this question being down voted? Am I not being clear on something?

Comment: Dunno, maybe the people feel you haven't been very clear as to what you've tried and what you're actually looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to find friends of the active Facebook user who work in the same field of employment. I coded it just like similar working functions and it won't run. I will add working functions above. An up vote would be appreciated : )